# Rails/Mongoid update_attributes ignoring persisted nested attributes validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I've got a Mongoid "Node" model that "has_many" addresses (Address class).

I'm using a nested form to manage addresses and I'm able to create, update, destroy  node's addresses successfully.

The problem is with Address validators : When validation fails on a new Address, update_attibutes fails and errors are displayed. But when trying to update an existing address with a invalid value, Address validators are triggered and fails (checked through log), but Node's update_attributes returns true and no error is displayed (the address keeps it's value unchanged).

When trying to update an existing address with invalid value and create a new invalid address at the same time to force update_attributes to fail, my form fails because of the new address, but there's no error on the existing address and its (valid) value is restored.

Is there a different behavior between new and persisted nested attributes validation ?

Here's the header of my Node class :

```rb
class Node

  # INCLUSIONS

    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

  # RELATIONS

    belongs_to              :organization
    has_and_belongs_to_many :platforms
    has_many                :addresses

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
```

Address class (class methods skipped) (note that there are overloaded getters & setters but they doesn't seem to be the cause) :

```rb
class Address

  # INCLUSIONS

    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

  # RELATIONS

    belongs_to :node

  # FIELDS

    field :address, type: String
    field :nat,     type: String
    field :description

  # VALIDATIONS

    validates :address, :node,
      presence: true

    # Validates address and nat validity
    validate do
      [:address, :nat].each do |field|
        errors.add(field, :invalid) unless self[field].blank? || self.class.valid_hex?(self[field])
      end
    end

  # INSTANCE METHODS

    # Address getter
    def address
      return self.class.hex_to_ip(self[:address]).to_s if self.class.valid_hex? self[:address]
      self[:address]
    end

    # Address setter
    def address= value
      self[:address] = self.class.valid_ip?(value) ? self.class.ip_to_hex(value) : value
    end

    # NAT address getter
    def nat
      return self.class.hex_to_ip(self[:nat]).to_s if self.class.valid_hex? self[:nat]
      self[:nat]
    end

    # NAT Address setter
    def nat= value
      self[:nat] = self.class.valid_ip?(value) ? self.class.ip_to_hex(value) : value
    end

end
```

update method of NodesController :

```rb
def update
  @node = platform.nodes.find_by name: params[:id]
  if @node.update_attributes params[:node]
    flash[:success] = t_flash :update_success, @node
    redirect_to platforms_platform_node_path(organization, platform, @node)
  else
    flash.now[:error] = t_flash :update_error, @node, count: @node.errors.count
    render :form
  end
end
```

I've tried adding [validates_associated :addresses](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validates_associated) in Node class but it doesn't change anything (and it doesn't seem to be necessary since new addresses are validated without this).

I've also tried replacing getters & setters with after_initialize/before_save callbacks and I had the same problem.

Rails v3.2.6 / Mongoid v3.0.1

### Update : params[:node] content

When submitting a new valid address (no error) :

```
{"name"=>"Test", "addresses_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"address"=>"1.2.3.4", "description"=>"", "nat"=>""}}}
```

When submitting a new address with invalid format (error
   successfully displayed) :

```
{"name"=>"Test", "addresses_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"address"=>"fdgfdgfdgfd", "description"=>"", "nat"=>""}}}
```

When updating a valid address with invalid value (no error bu it should) :

```
{"name"=>"Test", "addresses_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"5007e1c26fad9db41f000008", "address"=>"dsfsdfsdf", "description"=>"", "nat"=>""}}}
```

Comment: please paste your params[:node] value

Comment: I've updated the question with params[:node]

Comment: If you update a document with invalid values, do they get set back to the last persisted value? I have the same issue. In my case, the association validates the presence of a value. If I empty the field, it gets set back to its previous value.

Comment: @Hiasinho : Absolutely, as said at the end of the 4th paragraph of my question ;o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this git commit https://github.com/jiren/mongoid/commit/9ebb8af8514ea70c66a7dbe64be20bc7407a2829

You can use this gem this issue is fixed.

Comment: The fork is based on a very old version of Mongoid 3 (wasn't even in RC in 02/2012?). I've sent this link to mongoid Google group to check if they can include it. In the meantime, I'll try writing a monkey patch with the commit you provided.

Comment: PS : Google group link : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoid/pREjqqSSnMU

Comment: Opened an issue with your link on official mongoid github : https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2308

Comment: Your answer isn't really a solution but it helped unfreezing the situation since mongoid dev has now fixed the issue based on your link. So I check it. Thanks!

Comment: Here is the official fix with specs tests: https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/commit/eb5f1d9444f500f0f0f7507196c24d3666d24627 (a "little" more complex than jiren's fork solution ;o) )